# docusign callback url not working with ip address

Tags: docusignapi

We have downloaded sample application(sample-app-loanco-nodejs-master) from docusign website and trying to run with the account details of our developer account. It is working fine with callBackUrl as  "http://localhost:3801/ds/callback" in /routes/index.js, however it is not working with IP address of the same machine. It gives an error that "The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign", The same URI(with ip address) has been registered with app on docusign developers website.
Please help in understanding the issue and propose a solution for the same.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You  have to register the callback address in the Apps and Keys page for your Integration key under Additional Settings -> Redirect Uris.

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/

Comment: Also note that the URL you register has to match *exactly* what's in the authorization url you're hitting. If you register `https://127.0.0.1/example` but attempt to hit `http://127.0.0.1/example` you will get the redirect uri not registered error.

Comment: Thank you Drew I am registering redirect url under apps and keys eg http://127.0.0.1 and hitting same but still it gives error as mentioned above

Comment: Are you adding the url under the correct integration key ?

Comment: One reason I can think of is that your public and private ip addresses are different. This is possible if are working behind an organisation's network. You can check your public ip address using whatismyip on google